# Force DataGridView to commit edit

Tags: .net, datagridview

DataGridView save changes only when a cell looses focus or new row is selected.
Users can forget to do so specially on the last row in a grid. How to commit changes so to be available into ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified) when pressing a "save" button or exit program?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `EndEdit` method, which commits and ends the edit operation on the current cell.

```
myDataGridView.EndEdit()
```

See more details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.endedit(v=vs.110).aspx).